# Include both assignment and test on assigned value in while loop for Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, idioms

I'm looking to find the last line of a text file using a rather standard while-loop idiom I find often used in Java.

I have a less compact version working. But the one I would like to use does not appear to be valid syntax in Kotlin. My preferred method includes an assignment and a `Boolean` test on that assignment in the same line.

Admittedly this is a small matter, but I'm looking to better implement my Kotlin code.

```
fun readLastLine(file:File):String {
    val bufferedReader = file.bufferedReader()
    var lastLine=""

    //valid
    var current = bufferedReader.readLine()
    while(current != null) {
        lastLine=current
        current = bufferedReader.readLine()
    }
    //return lastLine

    //not valid...
    //while((current=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
    //    lastLine=current
    //}

   //responding to comment below, 
   //preferred/terse answer using file.readLines
   //this reads all the lines into a list, then returns the last
   return file.readLines().last()
}
```

Comment: I understand your interest is purely of academic nature. However, in case anyone comes looking for an implementation to your sample problem I suggest you mention the idiomatic solution using `file.readLines().last()`

Comment: FYI, I came across a discussion of the assignment from an expression.  It seems this is legitimate design question for the Kotlin language which has been answered by the designers: [kotlin forum](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/assignment-not-allow-in-while-expression/339/13)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Kotlin, an assignment is not an expression whose value is equal to the assigned value.

You can combine two statements using `run` function in Kotlin. This function returns the value of the the last expression.

```
var current = ""
while (run {
    current = bufferedReader.readLine()
    current != null
}) { // or while (run { current = bufferedReader.readLine(); current != null }) {
    lastLine = current
}
```

However, you can further reduce the code using `File.forEachLine()` in Kotlin.

```
fun readLastLine(file: File): String {
    var lastLine = ""
    file.forEachLine { line ->
        lastLine = line
    }
    return lastLine
}
```

Or shorter,

```
fun readLastLine(file: File): String {
    var lastLine = ""
    file.forEachLine { lastLine = it }
    return lastLine
}
```

This uses `BufferedReader` and closes automatically internally: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/for-each-line.html